# make cordova sqlite plugin use 1 thread in ios

Tags: ios, multithreading, sqlite, cordova

I'm using pouchDb and sqllite and my application works great in android but on iOS I have some conflicts with data.

I really think it's because ios uses a thread pool with sqlite and android does not.

Is there a way to configure sqlite to use 1 pool in iOS?

thanks!

UPDATE:
I solved my problem using the latest version of the sqllite plugin in this way:

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git#r1.0.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setting Single-Threaded Mode in SQLite**

If you're using the stock SQLite on iOS you won't be able to set the compile-time threading flags. You may however be able to set the [start-up or per-connection run-time settings](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html):

> Start-time selection of threading mode
>
> Assuming that the compile-time threading mode is not single-thread,
>   then the threading mode can be changed during initialization using the
>   sqlite3_config() interface. The SQLITE_CONFIG_SINGLETHREAD verb puts
>   SQLite into single-thread mode, the SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD verb
>   sets multi-thread mode, and the SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED verb sets
>   serialized mode.
>
> Run-time selection of threading mode
>
> If single-thread mode has not been selected at compile-time or
>   start-time, then individual database connections can be created as
>   either multi-thread or serialized. It is not possible to downgrade an
>   individual database connection to single-thread mode. Nor is it
>   possible to escalate an individual database connection if the
>   compile-time or start-time mode is single-thread.
>
> The threading mode for an individual database connection is determined
>   by flags given as the third argument to sqlite3_open_v2(). The
>   SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX flag causes the database connection to be in the
>   multi-thread mode and the SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX flag causes the
>   connection to be in serialized mode. If neither flag is specified or
>   if sqlite3_open() or sqlite3_open16() are used instead of
>   sqlite3_open_v2(), then the default mode determined by the
>   compile-time and start-time settings is used.

**Using Serial Queues in Objective-C**

If this does not work for you then you can create a serial Objective-C queue and perform all of your SQLite queries on it:

```
dispatch_queue_t SQLiteQueue;

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    SQLiteQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycorp.product.sqlite", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
});
```

That will initialize the queue. Then you call:

```
dispatch_sync(SQLiteQueue, ^(){
    //[db execute:@"select count(*) from table"];   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with the SQLite Plugin rather than with PouchDB. You might want to check their documentation or file a bug over there: https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

Also in general I can say that PouchDB is regularly (and very rigorously!) tested against the standard WebSQL and IndexedDB adapters, but not (currently) against the SQLite Plugin. I often hear reports of bugs when using the SQLite Plugin, so use that information however you like...

More info about adapters here: http://pouchdb.com/adapters.html#pouchdb_in_the_browser